# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt[n]{n} - 1}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, convergence-divergence

> I am looking for the convergence of
> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt[n]{n} - 1}n$$

I have tried ratio test/ root test and tried to compare with other convergent series but I do not get anywhere. Also, limit comparison of $a_n$ didn't seems to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\ln x= 0$ we have  $\exp(x\ln x) \sim 1+x\ln x$, and hence,   $$\frac{n^{1/n} - 1}{n} = \frac1n\left(\exp\left(-\frac1n\ln(\frac1n)\right)-1\right)\sim - \frac1{n^2}\ln(\frac1n) = \frac{\ln n}{n^2}$$
hence the convergence follows [by Bertrand criteria](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9rie_de_Bertrand) or [by Cauchy condensation test.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) or comparison test as follows

$$n^{3/2}\frac{\ln n}{n^2}= \frac{\ln n}{n^{1/2}}\to 0,~~as~~n\to\infty\implies \frac{\ln n}{n^2}\le \frac{C}{n^{3/2}}$$

Comment: Very frankly, I didn't know that and I believe there is a "much easier" way to solve it (it's an exam problem).

Comment: I got it now that you added Cauchy condensation test. Thanks!

Comment: @KartikSharma what criteria have you done in class there are many other way to solve this

Answer (score 4):

Use:

$\sqrt[n]{n} \le 1+ \dfrac{2}{\sqrt n}, \in \mathbb {Z^+}, n \ge 1.$

$a_n: = \dfrac{n^{1/n}-1}{n} \le \dfrac{2}{n^{3/2}}.$

Hence sum convergent.

Appended:

For $x \ge 0$, $n\ge 2 :$

$(1+x)^n \ge (n^2/4)x^2.$

(Proof: Use Binomial theorem.)

Set $x =\dfrac{2}{√n},$ then

$(1+x)^n = (1+2/√n)^n \ge$

$ (n^2/4)(4/n)= n.$

Hence: $1+2/√n \ge n^{1/n}$.

Comment: How do you get the first inequality ?

Comment: Yves. Appended. OK now? Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$ \frac{n^{1/n} - 1}{n}\sim \frac{\log n}{n^2}$$

thus the given series converges by compartison with

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^\frac32}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$t:=\frac{n^{1/n}-1}n$$ so that by the binomial theorem

$$(1+nt)^n=1+n^2t+\frac{n^3(n-1)}2t^2+R(t)=n$$ where $R(t)$ is positive. By solving the quadratic equation for the positive root, we can easily show that

$$t=O(n^{-3/2})$$ and this ensures convergence.